# Simple Swift Framework Dependency

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I can't seem to get dependencies between Swift-based projects/frameworks/apps in Xcode correct.

I create an IOS Framework 'Foo' in Swift with two files.  Then I create an IOS App 'Bar' in Swift (as a Master/Detail App).  In 'Bar' source files I use Foo functionality.  Of course it doesn't compile; I want to have a relationship whereby 'Bar' depends on 'Foo'.  How to create that dependency?

I've tried:

1. Add 'import Foo' to 'Bar' source.  No dice; 'Foo' isn't a 'real' Framework; the 'import' isn't recognized.  How to make 'Foo' a real framework?
2. Drag 'Foo.xcodeproj' under 'Bar'; Add 'target dependency' and 'Link Binary with Library' relationships. No dice. Compiler reports issues at points in 'Bar' where 'Foo' functionality is used.
3. Drag 'Foo.xcodeproj' next to 'Bar' to create a workspace.  No dice; can't establish relationships.

So that am I missing?

Comment: I think "2" should work. Just a confirmation, did you make Bar classes `public`?

Comment: Um, no actually.  I'd forgotten that `internal` is the default.  I went back and added `public` to classes, properties and functions and presto, it works.

Comment: Needless to say, I mean "Foo classes", not "Bar classes". glad to hear that :)

Comment: Not so fast.  I have functions added in an NSManagedObject extension.  Making the functions and the extension public doesn't allow those functions to be recognized at their point of use.  Let me try some more.

Comment: Okay, got it. Made sure 'Foo' was declared as a `module` in the 'Build Settings'; used `import Foo` in 'Bar' sources; declared `Foo` .swift w/ proper public annotations.  That gets it done.  Thanks.